# JSON Post response is causing out of memory exceptions

Tags: javascript, c#, html, json, performance

the responses to my posts from my C# sever side seem to be too big

```
$.post(geographicServiceUrl + "/addPolygon",
    { name: document.getElementById('polygonName').value, path: latLongStrings }
    , function (data) {

       doSomeStuff(data);

    });
```

in fact my responses are so huge i get an out of memory exception, so my question is, is there a more efficient way of handling large responses without negatively impacting speed?

Comment: what's the size of your response

Comment: well it depends on how much the clients requests, there technically isnt any limit,   so im not exactly sure on what size i get the out of memory exception on

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe try to split the calls and response, but if you crash your browser with it.... I really think you probably simply have an insane amount of data and should think about reducing it.